# Android Libgdx app startes only after resinstall or reboot

Tags: android, libgdx

The main problem is that the app starts only after installation or reboot.
Second time the application does not run correctly.
Details are below.

I have encountered with a few strange problems

```
1) Libgdx did not detect screen size correctly on Android 4 in
   SCREEN_WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
```

I got `369*320` instead of `960*540`

I do as follows to fight with this problem:

- I run main `Activity` class, where I get screen size using `Display`
- Then I run `AndroidApplication` class where I start Admob and Libgdx class.

2) The second problem is that the app starts
with no initialized values, that is to say with the same memory.
No initialization of values such as `boolean abc=false;`
Looks like invalid exit?

- In Libgdx class (third class) I set some value `exit=true` and exit,
  disposing all textures. Program returns to the second class .

  ```
  public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Data.exit) finish();
  ```

Second class returns to main activity
which checks `exit` in the same manner

3) Next interesting thing is that now `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()`
gets screen size correctly. Mistery...

4) If so, I remade the app.
And now main class starts Libgdx class.
It works and exits good, but only first time after installation or reboot.
Seconds time Libgdx `onCreate` starts, but `render()` does not.
Looks like invalid exit after first start again:
The main class code is here

```
 public class MyActivity extends AndroidApplication 
      implements IActivityRequestHandler {
  public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    context.startService(new Intent(context, BillingService.class));
    ....
    // Create the libgdx View
    View gameView = initializeForView(new MyGame(this), false);

    // Create and setup the AdMob view
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "aaaaaaa");
  }

@Override
public synchronized void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: If you start your app, then "exit" it, and then start a lot of (say 5 or 6) other apps, then start your app, does it start?  (I suspect there is a problem with restarting in the old JVM process, vs. starting a new JVM process, which is usually related to 'static' state in the app.)

Comment: No, it does not start after starting 5-6 apps.

Answer (score 0):

You are using statics. They preserve their value when you close the app, and you open it again before Android destroys the process, hence using the same VM. You cannot control when Android will destroy it, so try to initialize these variables in the constructor/create method of their class.

Instead of:

```
static boolean abc=false;
```

Use:

```
static boolean abc;

public MyClass/create(){
    abc=false;
}
```

Or do not use statics unless necessary.